# Change visibility an item on other tabarview not working on setState() Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have  checkbox1 on tabbar 1 and when clicked I set tabbar2's checkbox's visibility to true and step programmatically to tabbar2. However checkbox2 is not appears, just in case I click back on tabbar1 an come back to tabbar2 manually.

I use on tabbar1

```
onChanged: (bool? value) {
    setState(() {
        tab1CheckBox = value;
    });
//step process to Tabbar2
},
```

and tabbar2

```
Visibility(
visible: tab1CheckBox!,
child: Checkbox(
  value: tab2CheckBox,
  onChanged: (bool? value) {
    setState(() {
      tab2CheckBox = value;                   
    });
  },
))
```

What should I do something else? The tab1CheckBox = value; is in separet setState() and checkbox2' visibility depends on tab1CheckBox

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share your full code?

Comment: I modified the code

Comment: please include a _complete_ example, as others will be able to help you more accurately. The snippet should be runnable.

Comment: I created the mini project here
https://zapp.run/edit/zi8q06oai8r0?lazy=false&split=50&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart:586-590

The problem occurs only when programmatic tab steps is used.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

`_tabController.index = 1;`

after the setState to this

`_tabController.animateTo((_tabController.index + 1) % 2);`

Comment: I think I did the same in this examaple: https://zapp.run/edit/zi8q06oai8r0?lazy=false&split=50&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

Comment: fascinating, working, thank you ver much.